# Ordenar datas no DataTables

Tags: jquery-datatables

Estou utilizando o DataTables.js para renderizar minhas tabelas, o problema é que a data exibida na tabela já está convertida para d/m/Y e se eu clicar em reordenar pela coluna ele não vai exibir os dados corretamente, pois não tem como ordenar em ordem crescente / decrescente por esse tipo de campo, apenas com Y/m/d daria para reordenar, teria alguma solução para esse problema?

PS: a saída mais fácil que encontrei foi exibir a data padrão do MySql no formato Y/m/d, mas a leitura para o usuário fica bem complicada e na hora de exportar ele exporta o que está na tela.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui usando a documentação com os plugins do moment e date-time-moment:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD/MM/YYYY' );
```

Answer (score 0):

O que pode ser feito é colocar o script

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
 "date-br-pre": function ( a ) {
  if (a == null || a == "") {
   return 0;
  }
  var brDatea = a.split('/');
  return (brDatea[2] + brDatea[1] + brDatea[0]) * 1;
 },

 "date-br-asc": function ( a, b ) {
  return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
 },

 "date-br-desc": function ( a, b ) {
  return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
 }
} );
```

logo acima do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

e depois colocar uma definição de coluna no target da sua coluna

```
  columnDefs: [ 
                { type: 'date-br', targets: 0 } // onde 0 é a sua coluna data, a primeira é 0
                    ],
```